# How to change name of DVD directory

Tags: dvd, rename

I had K3b burn some data to a rewrite-able DVD.

My file manager shows it as "K3b data project"

I want to rename it to a sensible name like DVD_Disk.

```
sudo mv '/media/andy/K3b data project' DVD
mv: cannot move '/media/andy/K3b data project' to 'DVD': Device or resource busy
andy@7 /media/andy>
```

How can I do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can not change the label of the disk once it has been written too. You can do the following. Copy the data off the disk. Format the disk with the label you want and then write the data back on.